# Why my styles.css successfully uploaded but doesn't work?

Tags: html, css

I tried to add css style to my Django web-app, but something goes wrong...
There you can see  tag and i even take full link to css file, if i try load this link i see my css code and all work correctly, but css style doesn't work on button and other elements
This is my html code:

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link media="screen" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/blog/css/styles.css" />

    <title>
        {% block title %}
        {% endblock %}
    </title>
    {% block mainmenu %}
    {% for m in menu %}
    <a href="{% url m.url_name %}">{{ m.title }}</a>
    {% endfor %}
    {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
    <a href="{% url 'logout' %}">Logout</a>
    {% else %}
    <a href="{% url 'login' %}">Login</a>
    {% endif %}
    {% endblock mainmenu %}
    {{ username }}


</head>
<body>

{% block content %}
{% endblock %}

</body>
</html>
```

This is my css:

```
* {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

.button.vote {
width: auto;
font-size: 100%;
text-align: center;
font-style: normal;
color: black;
background-color: #CCCCCC;
border-radius: 6px;
border: 2px solid black;
transition: 0.3s;
padding: 3px 15px;
}

.button.vote:hover {
background-color: #181818;
color: grey;
}
```

this is my html code where i trying to create button with style:

```
<ul>
    {% if post.is_published %}
    <h1>
        Post({{ post.rating }}) by {{post.author}}({{ post.author.rating }}):
        <br>
        Title:
        <br>
        {{post.title}}
        <br>
        Content:
        <br>
        {{post.content | linebreaks}}
    </h1>
    {% if post.photo %}
    <img style="width: 20%; height: 20%;" src="{{ post.photo.url }}">
    {% endif %}

    {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}

    {% if username_for_check == author_for_check %}
    <form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <button type="submit" name="delete_post" value="{{post.slug}}">Delete post</button>
    </form>
    {% endif %}

    <br>

    <form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <button class="vote" type="submit" name="vote_pro" value="{{post.slug}}" style="background-color:
        {% if request.user in votes_pro %} grey; {% else %} white; {% endif %}">Pro
        </button>
    </form>
    {{post.rating}}
    <form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <button class="vote" type="submit" name="vote_contra" value="{{post.slug}}" style="background-color:
        {% if request.user in votes_contra %} grey; {% else %} white; {% endif %}">Contra
        </button>
    </form>
    {% endif %}
    {% else %}
    <h1>Unfortunately, this post was unpublished</h1>
    {% endif %}
</ul>
```

I tried a lot of ways to fix this error(on this site), but nothing helps me

Comment: I don’t see an element with the class name “button” and “vote” in your template. Show us the generated HTML output.

Comment: Are there any other stylesheets being loaded that might be overwriting your styles?

Comment: No, there aren't any other stylesheets

Comment: I will upload html code with button in few minutes

Comment: The problem isn't specifically in the button, but in the fact that no styles are applied.